# Drawing Bijections for one set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just want to make sure I understand what to do when asked to draw bijections.

So when I am asked Draw the diagrams (as we did in class) for all bijections $f : A\to A$ when the set $A$ is $A = \{1, 2\}$

Do I make two columns of $1$ and $2$ because it is a bijection of one set, then draw the lines? But, I also do it four times because there can be four combinations.

Comment: It depends on whether you are being asked to draw a single bijection, or all the possible bijections.

Comment: @BadAtMaths I believe all bijections

Comment: There are $2^2 = 4$ functions from $A = \{1, 2\}$ to itself, but there are only two bijections since each element in the domain must be mapped to a distinct element in the range.  I suggest that you revise your question by listing your proposed bijections, then asking readers to verify that you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that what’s wanted is something like this, with one diagram for each bijection:

[image]

Note that while there are two other functions from $A$ to $A$, neither of them is a bijection.

Comment: oh so these are the only two bijections? Thanks so much

Comment: @Csci319: You’re welcome. Yes, the other two maps send both elements of the set to the same place, so they’re not bijections.

Comment: is there a formula to figure out how many bijections there are for a larger set? Because I have another one like this $A={1,2,3,4}$ ?

Comment: @Csci319: Basic multiplication principle. Suppose that you’re building a bijection $f$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. There are $n$ choices for $f(1)$. Once you’ve chosen $f(1)$, there are $n-1$ remaining possibilities for $f(2)$, and so on, so you get $n!$ possibilities.

Comment: so for $A=1,2,3,4$ I can draw $4!$ bijections?

Comment: @Csci319: I’m afraid so; $24$ is a lot to draw, but it’s still doable. With $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ it would be $120$, which is already getting ridiculous.